# dart - map value changes without setting it explicitly

Tags: dictionary, dart

A Dart question:
In the following, to show (in my mind) "normal behaviour", the value of the key-value pair is not changed without explicitly setting it:

```dart
Map<String,String> mup = {};
mup['a']='fred';
var val = mup['a'];// val==fred
val = 'joe'; 
print(mup); // (a: fred} - unchanged
mup['a']=val; //set
print(mup); // (a: joe} - changed OK
```

A strange way to show it, but nothing surprising there.
But if the value is a list, if the list value is changed, the map is updated immediately:

```dart
Map<String,List> mup = {};
mup['a']=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
var val = mup['a'];
val[1]=66;
print (mup);//{a: [1, 66, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

So **mup** has changed without explicitly changing it! What is going on...please?

Surprising to me, but I **am** a beginner!

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var val = mup['a']` returns a reference to the list `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` not a copy.
If you modify it this is also reflected in the list inside the map which is in fact the same list.

Basically you can imagine it as looking at the same thing in a box but from two different holes.

Comment: @mezoni. Thanks both. I think I see why it wouldn't apply for immutable strings, but it does not apply to ints (just tested it map<string,int>), which are objects. Why not? S

Comment: `int` is also immutable. You can`t change the value of an `int` you can only assign another instance (with another value).